# Generating an Ethereum wallet with encseed and ethaddr

Tags: wallets

I know very little about Ethereum. I'm trying to generate an Ethereum wallet in JSON format that will have `encseed` and `ethaddr`. I've been looking online and couldn't find a way to do that. Can someone tell me how to do that? Or generate a wallet like that for me with a known password?

Comment: can you pls help me how to bruteforce EthSale JSON files. My backup json files include encseed.

Answer (score 6):

There are currently 3 formats for JSON files: EthSale, v1, and v3.

`encseed` is the encryption seed and is only found in the EthSale JSON files.

There are 2 methods that I know of to generate these formats:

- You can use [pyethsaletool](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethsaletool) which will generate a ETH sale wallet which has both `encseed` and `ethaddr`.
- axic has made a cool tool [called ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) that handles a whole bunch of stuff pertaining to wallet generation and converting between various formats, including EthSale

The real question is why you want to generate a wallet like this? V3 is the current standard and what I would recommend. You can easily create that via geth or Ethereum Wallet.